# Is there a command line command I can use to find the number of local groups?

Tags: command-line-arguments

Is there a command line command I can use to find the number of local groups without having to count them one by one from the output of the net localgroup command? I've tried the help info for net localgroup and it doesn't give many options.

Comment: What's wrong with using `wc`?

Comment: What OS?        (Padding goes here)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What is `wc`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via PowerShell. Open PowerShell and type the following command:

```
$m = get-wmiobject win32_group | measure
$m.Count
```

References:

1. https://www.petri.com/use-powershell-to-find-local-groups-and-members
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526285/how-to-count-objects-in-powershell